# How to build a grid of images if they have to be relatively positioned

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a grid of images. The elements are relatively positioned so float: left doesn't seem to stack them. Is there a better way to do this? Heres the code:

CSS:

```
#master {

    width: 940px;
    outline: solid 1px #000;

}

#img_grid1 h2 {

    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 100px;
}



img.off {

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;

}

img.on {

    position: absolute;
    left:0; top: 0;

}

ul#img_grid1 { position: relative; }

ul#img_grid1 li {

    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none; 


}

.copy { 

    position: relative; 
    width: 200px; 
    top: 70px; 
    left: 40px;

}

.copy p { color: #FFF; }

/* slightly enhanced, universal clearfix hack */
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

HTML:

```
<div id="master">

<br />

<ul id="img_grid1">

  <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><img class="off" src="images/img1.jpg" alt=""/><img class="on" src="images/img1over.jpg" alt=""/><h2>Heading 1</h2><div class="copy"><p>Love walking? Check out our fantastic range of quality walking gear. Plus... find out more about our FREE boot fitting service or check our brand new gear guide.</p></div>
 </a></li>
 <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><img class="off" src="images/img1.jpg" alt=""/><img class="on" src="images/img1over.jpg" alt=""/><h2>Heading 1</h2><div class="copy"><p>Love walking? Check out our fantastic range of quality walking gear. Plus... find out more about our FREE boot fitting service or check our brand new gear guide.</p></div>
 </a></li>


</ul>
```

Not sure if its possible. I have tried floating the elements and that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line up the `li` using `display: inline-block;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ffU7S/)

CSS

```
ul {
    width: 1000px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" /></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you have a fix for IE 7

Comment: Actually am having IE9, and jsfiddle is not rendering perfectly on IE compatible mode so not able to test...btw you can leave IE7, as it will be scrapped out soon by others too..

Comment: Add *zoom: 1; *display:inline to get IE7 compatibility in all the classes in CSS where you have used display :inline-block;

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe Or you can save the styles in IE specific stylesheet :)

Comment: @Aratidgr8 Thanks for the IE7 support